# String Date time format conversion

Tags: .net, datetime, .net-core, datetime-format

What is the easiest way to convert "4/‎30‎/‎2020 ‎4‎:‎23‎:‎11‎ ‎PM" string to "2020-04-30T16:23:11" format? `Convert.ToDateTime([format])` has failed

Comment: What formatting did you try (what is "[format]")?

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime (I believe this is for the original string "4/‎30‎/‎2020 ‎4‎:‎23‎:‎11‎ ‎PM")

Comment: `"4/‎30‎/‎2020 ‎4‎:‎23‎:‎11‎ ‎PM"` ← Seems like this is the `en-US` culture. Parse it using `DateTime.Parse` and pass in the `CultureInfo` for `"en-US"`. Alternatively you could also pass in an explicit date format string and call `ParseExact` instead of `Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is a `DateTime`, then just use `DateTime.ToString()` :

```
string s = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

If the input is a string, then you could parse it to a `DataTime` first:

```
DataTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/d‎/dddd H‎:m‎:s‎ tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then convert it to a string using the method above.